# LayoutInflater with ContextThemeWrapper not always themed

Tags: java, android, android-context, android-theme, layout-inflater

I'm trying to inflate a layout with theme different from app default, and doing it like this:

```
final View view = context.getLayoutInflater().cloneInContext(new ContextThemeWrapper(context, getThemeForView())).inflate(R.layout.some_layout, root, false);
```

First time it's done view doesn't have theme I want, but main app theme. When view is recreated after few minutes, it has correct theme. Why is theme different when view is first created?

EDIT:
I can't set `android:theme` because I get theme dinamically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I first created view in `Activity.onCreate`. With some testing I found out that if I create view in `Activity.onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus)` when `hasFocus == true` works fine. I'm still not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

You can add

```
android:theme="@style/some_theme"
```

to the activity in the manifest file.

Comment: I simplified code, theme is get dinamically, but thanks anyway.